# VBA Run Time error sometimes but other times not when automatically connecting visio shapes

Tags: excel, vba, exception, visio

I have quite a large program, but what it does is scan down a data sheet and use that info to create diagrams. Once it places all the symbols it goes back and connects them with this function I wrote, the function works by placing a connector and then changing the begin x and end x parts of its shape sheet to the Connection point row of the two objects it is connecting. The macro will run fine, do a whole bunch of connections without issue, and then randomly it will through a `Run-time error '-2032465768 ...` and say, "An exception occured". What I don't understand is that it placed the connector properly on a similar part of the same diagram, and when I look at the shape sheet of the two objects, their connection points are defined. Additionally, it happens sporadically other times I run it, and sometimes when I re-run it, it works fine on the part that it had previously encountered the exception.

This is the error message:[image]

The function for connecting the two objects is:

```
Sub ConnectShapes(Diagram As clsNewDiagram, Shape1 As Visio.Shape, Shape1ConnectionNum, Shape2 As Visio.Shape, Shape2ConnectionNum, Optional Color As Integer = LineColor.BLACK)
    Dim Connector As Visio.Shape
    Set Connector = Diagram.CurrentPage.Drop(Diagram.Document.Masters.ItemU("Dynamic connector"), 0#, 0#)
    Dim vsoCell1 As Visio.Cell
    Dim vsoCell2 As Visio.Cell
    Set vsoCell1 = Connector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXForm1D, vis1DBeginX)
    Set vsoCell2 = Shape1.CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, Shape1ConnectionNum, 0)
    vsoCell1.GlueTo vsoCell2
    Set vsoCell1 = Connector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXForm1D, vis1DEndX)
    Set vsoCell2 = Shape2.CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, Shape2ConnectionNum, 0)
    vsoCell1.GlueTo vsoCell2
    Connector.SendToBack
    
    'Connector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowShapeLayout, visSLOLineRouteExt).FormulaU = "2" ' For curved connector.
    'Connector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowShapeLayout, visSLOConFixedCode).FormulaU = "3"
    
    If Color = LineColor.FIBER Then
        Connector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,0,255))"
    ElseIf Color = LineColor.DC Then
        Connector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,102,0))"
    ElseIf Color = LineColor.RET Then
        Connector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(0,202,0))"
    End If     
End Sub
```

When I press debug it doesn't like this line, but it worked on other symbols

On
[image]
Here is a picture of its output, as you can see it successfully connected the other symbols, and I have absolutely no idea why it is throughing this error all of a sudden, it didn't used to.
[image]

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing all your code, or to not have access to your diagram to look at it in detail. I'll guess though that something else is causing your code to generate an incorrect reference to Shape2.

Comment: Usually with Visio the exception occurred means the object being referenced is gone, so it's not Nothing, but it's not really something either. Since it seems to work okay when you try again, you might find a short Sleep call may fix it, or you could write an error handler that just tries the same line like 3 times and then gives up if there's an error. I know it's hacky, but Visio VBA kinda forces my hand that way, sometimes